# How to convert handwriting to text programmatically in android Application

Tags: android, android-layout, handwriting-recognition, digital-handwritting

I have a requirement where I have to convert the user **hand written text using stylus into digital text** as and when they write or convert after they completes scribbling.

Is there any library available in Android to do this or steps to do also will help me.

Comment: With lot of googling, I found a perfect library which can convert the hand written scripts into texts, numbers and shapes and it is proposed for web applications. Trying to get the same for Android Mobile Application. If any one have experienced before, please do contribute.

Answer (score 1):

See OCR library [ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine for Android](http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/android/). But beware that doing OCR on a device can be quite expensive for CPU

Comment: I need a library with free licence since it is going to be a free application.